# Creation of infinite 'step' function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose I have a simple function such as $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} x)^2$, and I want to create a 'stepped' function that, for each integer $x$, jumps by $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} x)^2$ - in effect, a stepped summation of $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} x)^2$ for integer $x$. Is there anything wrong with writing it like this?

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (\sin \frac{\pi}{5} \lfloor x \rfloor)^2$$

This seems logical to me:

- $x=0$ yields $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} 0)^2=0$
- $x=1$ yields $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} 0)^2+(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} 1)^2=0+0.345=0.345$
- $x=3$ yields $(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} 0)^2+(\sin \frac{\pi}{5} 1)^2+(\sin
     \frac{\pi}{5} 3)^2=0+0.345+0.904=1.249$
- etc

Not only does it seem logical to me, but it works - as you can see from this Mathematica plot, which is exactly what I was trying to create:

[image]

But I'm confused. I used this general construction ($\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$) on another post (hopefully now deleted as it was pretty garbled), and got shot down for creating an expression that 'wasn't meaningful'.

So, is there a *correct* way to create the stepped function outlined above? Or do I have the construction right, and I was simply communicating poorly in previous posts?

Comment: You`re using the same letter to denote the changing index of summation and the upper limit value,which is confusing to me. Is the $[x]$ in the sin "running " or is it the same as the upper summation limit?

Comment: Show us what you typed into Mathematica and we can immediately explain to you what the mistake is.

Comment: I included the example to help clarify this. Set $x$ to $0$: evaluate it, and the result is $0$. Set $x$ to $0.5$: evaluate: well it's $\lfloor x \rfloor$, so still $0$. Set $x$ to $1$, and now you have the *sum* of the $\sin$ function's value in the range $x=0$ to $x=1$. And so on. The $\sin$ element is providing the numbers which are then summed, up to and including the current value of $x$.

Comment: I have now amended the image above to include the Mathematica input. See above.

Comment: you don't need the $floor[x]$ inside summation, just put$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (\sin \frac{\pi}{5}k)^2$

Comment: OK, I see. That notation is clearer, but same result. Much appreciated. How do I mark that as the answer?

Comment: you cannot mark comments as the answer; somebody has to summarize the comments and post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your summation:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$
This causes confusion because how can the upper bound depend on the running variable itself? The solution is to define a new variable for the summation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (\sin \frac{\pi}{5} \lfloor k \rfloor)^2.$$